# How to cover this jdbctemplate.call method in testng

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, jdbctemplate, testng-eclipse

```
Public testResponse Test(int number){
log.info("started",spalphabets,number);
var output = jdbcTemplate.call(connection -> {
var stmt = connection.prepareCall(spalphabets);
stmt.setInt(1,number);
stmt.setString(2,String.valueOf('apple'));
return stmt;
},getValue());
return Response
```

How to cover the call method parameters connection.preparecall in the above test response method using testng

Comment: It's not clear as to what you are asking. Can you please edit your question and add a complete sample along with what is your expectations?

Comment: Additionally you might want to refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-testing to learn how to work with jdbc templates